# Spring boot RequestBody with object fields that could be needed

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

How can I make my RequestBody accept a model with object fields that may or may not be included?

This is the Restcontroller endpoint I’m calling

```
@PatchMapping(value = "/projects/update/{projectNumber}")
public ResponseEntity<Object> updateProject(@PathVariable int projectNumber, @RequestBody RequestReviewUpdate rru)
{
    return reviewUpdateService.updateReview(projectNumber, rru);    
}
```

Here is the model @RequestBody is accepting

```
public class RequestReviewUpdate
{
    private UpdateProject project;
    private List<UpdateHlsd> reviews;
    private List<UpdateProjectLeadership> stakeHolders;
    
    public UpdateProject getProject() 
    {
        return project;
    }
    
    public List<UpdateHlsd> getReviews() 
    {
        return reviews;
    }
    
    public List<UpdateProjectLeadership> getStakeHolders() 
    {
        return stakeHolders;
    }
    
}
```

I want to be able to send a JSON could contain all object field, or some.

My JSON body could look something like this...

```
{
    "project": {
        "type": "HLSD"
    },
    "reviews": [
        {
            "id": 570,
            "requestedBy": "Name here",
            "notes":"test"
        }
        ],
    "stakeHolders": [
        {
            "id": 1088,
            "projectResource": "sid"
        }
    ]
}
```

Or this...ect

```
{
    "reviews": [
        {
            "id": 570,
            "requestedBy": "name",
            "notes":"test"
        }
 }
```

Or any other possible combinations.

Comment: In case you send only some properties in `JSON` payload only these properties will be set in `RequestReviewUpdate` class. Other properties, not available in `JSON` payload will be set to `null`, by default. In second case `stakeHolders` list and `project` object will be set to `null`. `reviews` list will be set to a one-element-list. It should work in this way by default. Have you experienced any problems with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make your `RequestReviewUpdate` optional, like:

```
@PatchMapping(value = "/projects/update/{projectNumber}")
public ResponseEntity<Object> updateProject(@PathVariable int projectNumber, @RequestBody(required=false) RequestReviewUpdate rru) {
    return reviewUpdateService.updateReview(projectNumber, rru);    
}
```

This will make your parameter optional, either entirely or partially. I.e. any member of the object you receive as an argument, might be present or absent.

Comment: Let's say I don't include the UpdateProject class in my RequestReviewUpdate model. What happens when I trying calling the getProject() method? Wouldn't my code error out because I'm calling a getting on a null object?

Comment: You will get `null`.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my problem.

Comment: I would if I could. My reputation is too low to upvote.